# Apache Superset PostgreSQL 'function date_trunc(unknown, bigint) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, apache-superset

**Context:** I have a dataset in Superset of parts - item ids, order year, avg annual cost. I'm trying to create what should be a super simple line chart showing the avg annual part cost by item over a annual time series. I'm a first time Superset user and I keep hitting the below error:

> PostgreSQL Error
> function date_trunc(unknown, bigint) does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT DATE_TRUNC('year', "Order_Year") AS __timestamp,
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> This may be triggered by:
> Issue 1002 - The database returned an unexpected error.
> See less

It looks like typing issue but I'm very unclear how to resolve the issue. Below is the query in SQL Lab that generates the error:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('year', "Order_Year") AS __timestamp,
       "COST_TYPE" AS "COST_TYPE",
       sum("Average_Annual_Part_Cost") AS "SUM(Average_Annual_Part_Cost)"
FROM "Part_Pricing_Unpivoted"
GROUP BY "COST_TYPE",
         DATE_TRUNC('year', "Order_Year")
ORDER BY "SUM(Average_Annual_Part_Cost)" DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

**Question:** Seems the `DATE_TRUNC` function is problematic - but why? Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message gives you the hint: apparently `Order_Year` is a `bigint` column, but `date_trunc()` only works with `date` or `timestamp` columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ a_horse_with_no_name, you're correct. I changed the type to a YYY-MM-DD format and the date_trunc function behaved as expected. Issue resolved.